# XML parse and grab item in Python 3.3 using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Im trying to parse an XML file and grab what's in between the tags:
 from the file and then writing it out in another file.
So i dont get the output i need in the output.xml, i want to get what's between the tags 
Here is a file sample https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topaudiobooks/limit=10/xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for imname in root.findall('<im:name>'):
    print (imname)

tree.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: Great! So what is your question?

Comment: So i dont get the output i need in the output.xml, i want to get what's between the tags <im:name></im:name>

Comment: Are your `print` statements print the correct strings? What does your XML file look like?

Comment: here is a sample with what the initial XML looks like.https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topaudiobooks/limit=10/xml        i dont understand what you mean by my print statements